# Is there a faster algorithm about this type of FFT

Tags: fft

my problem is:

A real sequence $C$, the length is  $N$ is multiple of 32, the pattern is as below:

$$C =\left(a_0,\, a_1,\, \ldots,\, a_{\frac N2-1},\,\, b_0,\, b_1,\,\ldots,\,  b_{\frac N2 -1}\right)$$

the other two sequence is $A$, $B$, length is also  $N$, as below:

$$\begin{align}
A &=(a_0,& a_1,& \ldots,& a_{\frac N2-1},&&0, &&\ldots&0&)\\
B &=(0,&& \ldots,& 0,& b_0,& b_1,&\ldots,&& b_{\frac N2-1}&)
\end{align}$$

you can see, $C= A+B$.

the DFT of sequence $C$ is known, but sequences $A$, $B$ and $C$ are all unknown.

I just want to know the DFT of sequence $A$ and $B$.

I know the ordinary method is

- perform a backward FFT to get sequence $C$, then
- sequence $A$ and $B$ becomes known, then
- perform forward FFT about $A$, the DFT of $B$ can be get by subtract DFT
  of $A$ from DFT of $C$;

but the computaton is too complicated,

Is there a faster computation method?

Comment: "too complicated" for what reason? Memory? CPU power? FPGA space?

Comment: I need to do it several times in a loop, so I want to find a faster method

Comment: that's not an answer for the above question. The question I should be asking is: How long does it *really* take, and why do you think you need to improve the performance of exactly this? FFT is highly optimized, and unless your $N$ is really large or you're doing anything highly optimized yourself, I'd claim you're trying to optimize a very cheap operation. So, what is your framework? How much time of your overall implementation is really spent in the ifft, and the two (smaller) forward ffts? what's your hardware? how large is $N$?

Comment: Marcus Müller, Thanks, N is 320, CPU is cortex-m4, no FPU,FFT is highly optimized,   I think if there is an indirect method to get the DFT result in the scenario as I describe above. If exist, CPU can do more times the DFT, the result then can be more precise.

Comment: so, what is your data type? on that CPU, I hope you're doing fixed-point?

Comment: data  is int16, doing fixed-point FFT

Comment: is there something else you know about A,B,C? any of these real-valued?

Comment: I took the liberty of formatting your question. In that go, I renamed your sequences, so that $A$ is the $(a_0,\ldots, 0,\ldots)$, sequence $B$ is $(0,\ldots b_0, \ldots)$ and $C=A+B$. Seemed a lot more logical that way.

Answer (score 1):

Alas, a multiplication by a rectangular window in the time domain is a convolution in the frequency domain.  Thus (assuming no other constraints on or knowledge about A or B), the DFT of A (or B) would have to be the convolution of the DFT of C with a twisty Sinc function, which is computationally far more expensive than 2 FFTs (except by fast convolution, which would require the same number of FFTs as your "ordinary" method).

Answer (score 0):

If your DFT of the sum-sequence is real-valued, then the original $C$ *must* be hermitian!

Thus, if we set

$$a = \left(a_0,\,\ldots,\, a_{\frac N2-1}\right)\\
b = \left(b_0,\,\ldots,\, b_{\frac N2-1}\right)$$

$$ A + B = C \in \mathbb R \\\implies\\
a_k = \left.b_{\frac N2 -1 - k}\right.^*  \\ \text{with } k \in \{0,1,\ldots,\frac N2-1\}
$$

That implies that 
$$\text{DFT}\{b\}(f) = \text{DFT}\{a\}(-f)^*$$
so, your subtraction method is actually superfluous; just calculate the transform of $a$ and read it backwards and invert the sign of the imaginary part. That is usually but a bit flip.

So your complexity reduces to the sum of complexities of

- 1x $\text{FFT}_{N}$
- 1x $\text{FFT}_{\frac N2}$
- $\frac N2$ bitflips

Comment: Thanks, Marcus Müller, DFT of sum-sequence **C** is complex number, not real number.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from @hotpaw2's analysis, what you need is brickwall zero-phase half-band low-pass filtering of the frequency domain data. Because you have all the data in-place, you can do forward-then-backward infinite impulse response (IIR) lowpass filtering. There is a very efficient half-band IIR filter structure, the two-path polyphase filter. You can calculate the coefficients using Laurent de Soras's [HIIR library](http://ldesoras.free.fr/prod.html). To convert the one-shot filters to periodic-input-output filters, you can wrap the tail of each IIR pass (with zero input) to the beginning of the output data and add it, with some stop condition depending on what numerical accuracy is needed.